# Prosody IM or Openfire?

Tags: xmpp, chat, multiuserchat

I am new to XMPP and after searching on internet I have decided to go with either Prosody or Openfire. I have decent knowledge in Java and my question is,

So should I select openfire because I know Java or Prosody because it's easy to setup and lightweight ? 
Is it necessary to know the language on which your XMPP server is written?

Comment: Any reason tigase is not on your list? It is also written in Java. That said, your question is not a good fit for stack overflow and is probably going to get closed.

Comment: @Flow As I mentioned I am new to XMPP and based on internet search result I got mostly 3 response i.e ejabberd, openfire and porsody. I'll close this question as soon as I get my answer.